# Read more than one node in rss xml

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

how can I read more category in this XML page? http://feeds.feedburner.com/passionea300allora?format=xml

Because, now I'm using this to read information:

```
var RSSdata = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                          select new RSSItem
                          {
                              Title1 = rss.Element("title").Value,
                              Description1 = rss.Element("description").Value,
                              Link1 = rss.Element("link").Value,
                              PubDate1 = rss.Element("pubDate").Value,
                              Category1 = rss.Element("category").Value
                          };
```

But this report me only first category (in the first news, at the moment, it is "Regolamento" at line 19).
I need to read more category and, if possible, author name too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `rss.Element("category")` , use `rss.Elements("category")`. That will return a `IEnumerable<XElement>`. You can change your property type to list of categories, or if you want to store values only you can store it into a `List<string>` like this:

```
var RSSdata = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
                      select new RSSItem
                      {
                          Title1 = (string)rss.Element("title"),
                          Description1 = (string)rss.Element("description"),
                          Link1 = (string)rss.Element("link"),
                          PubDate1 = (string)rss.Element("pubDate"),
                          Categories = rss.Elements("category")
                                           .Select(x => (string)x)
                                           .ToList();
                      };
```